message-driven-channel-adapter - concurrent processing of messages
Issue
We have a legacy application with the following message-driven-channel-adapter  configuration
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter 
    id="processRequest"        
    destination="requestFromLoader"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    max-concurrent-consumers="30"
    message-converter="xmlMarshalConverter"
    channel="jmsInChannel"
    error-channel="errorChannel"/>

with this configuration max-concurrent-consumers="30" we expected 30 parallel cosumers (processRequest-container-1 to 30) to consume the message but during testing we found that each consumers in turn consumes 10 messages, Eg - processRequest-container-1 processes messages 1 to 10 and then creates processRequest-container-2 and process 11 to 20 and so on..
if there are only 2 request this causes 2nd message to wait even though there are 29 other consumers.
Resolution
We added max-messages-per-task="1", this seems to yield the correct result but we are still testing with large volumes of messages.
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter 
    id="processRequest"        
    destination="requestFromLoader"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    max-concurrent-consumers="30"
    max-messages-per-task="1"
    message-converter="xmlMarshalConverter"
    channel="jmsInChannel"
    error-channel="errorChannel"/>

Questions

We notified that the name of the consumer in the logs (processRequest-container-1) is going upto 2000 or 3000 (processRequest-container-2546), and not restricted to processRequest-container-1 to processRequest-container-30, but in the first case without max-messages-per-task="1" it did not reach beyond processRequest-container-30, is it normal? or do we need to do something about it?

In the spring documentation max-messages-per-task="1" is defined as task to be performed per message, what is a task and how the max parallel consumer is affected by this?

is adding max-messages-per-task="1" correct or are we missing / overlooking something else?


any suggestion or comments are good. thanks in advance.

This question is more about Spring JMS, than Spring Integration.
It is probably better to read source code and Javadocs of the DefaultMessageListenerContainer which is used for the mentioned <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>.
There is an interesting comment which might explain your behavior:
/**
 * Specify the maximum number of concurrent consumers to create. Default is 1.
 * <p>If this setting is higher than "concurrentConsumers", the listener container
 * will dynamically schedule surplus consumers at runtime, provided that enough
 * incoming messages are encountered. Once the load goes down again, the number of
 * consumers will be reduced to the standard level ("concurrentConsumers") again.
 * <p>Raising the number of concurrent consumers is recommendable in order
 * to scale the consumption of messages coming in from a queue. However,
 * note that any ordering guarantees are lost once multiple consumers are
 * registered. In general, stick with 1 consumer for low-volume queues.
 * <p><b>Do not raise the number of concurrent consumers for a topic,
 * unless vendor-specific setup measures clearly allow for it.</b>
 * With regular setup, this would lead to concurrent consumption
 * of the same message, which is hardly ever desirable.
 * <p><b>This setting can be modified at runtime, for example through JMX.</b>
 * @see #setConcurrentConsumers
 */
public void setMaxConcurrentConsumers(int maxConcurrentConsumers) {

So, since you don't use concurrent-consumers="30" instead, it is normal that you got up to 30 dynamic instances which indeed got their ids incremented.
If you don't specify max-messages-per-task="1", the logic is like this:
        if (this.taskExecutor instanceof SchedulingTaskExecutor ste && ste.prefersShortLivedTasks()) {
            if (this.maxMessagesPerTask == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
                // TaskExecutor indicated a preference for short-lived tasks. According to
                // setMaxMessagesPerTask javadoc, we'll use 10 message per task in this case
                // unless the user specified a custom value.
                this.maxMessagesPerTask = 10;
            }
        }

Or your taskExecutor is not that SchedulingTaskExecutor (which is indeed by default) and therefore all your messages are handled by the same consumer instance.
Some docs are here as well: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/jms/using.html#jms-mdp
